# Batch file to "Script" a Database

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, command-line, scripting, batch-processing

Is it possible to somehow use a **.bat** file to script the schema and/or content of a SQL Server database?

I can do this via the wizard, but would like to streamline the creation of this file for source control purposes.

I would like to avoid the use of 3rd party tools, just limiting myself to the tools that come with SQL Server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a free tool called [SubCommander](http://subsonicproject.com/subcommander/using-the-command-line-tool-subcommander/) that is a part of the open source [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) software. I have successfully used this tool myself to create both schema and data "dumps" each night.

> You can script out your schema and
>   data (and then version it in your
>   favorite source control system) using
>   SubCommander. Simply use the command
>   "version" and tell SubCommander where
>   to put the data:
>
> **sonic.exe version /out Scripts**
>
> This will output a script file (.sql)
>   to the local scripts directory of your
>   project

You can also try using the [Microsoft SQL Server Database Publishing wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en), although i am not sure that you can use it in a bat file.